# Still not getting callback vs normal function call

Tags: c, pointers, callback, function-pointers

I have seen almost all popular question of callback here, but still not getting why use function pointer in callback instead of simply used callback via normal function. Here's the accepted answer *(modified)* of a popular question

```
void populate_array(int *array, size_t arraySize,
            int getNextValue(void))  // Note that, here I use normal function call.
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<arraySize; i++)
        array[i] = getNextValue();
}

int getNextRandomValue(void)
{
    return rand();
}

int main(void)
{
    int myarray[10];
    populate_array(myarray, 10, getNextRandomValue);
    ...
}
```

As you have seen above that still I can achieve callback implementation via simple function, so why use function pointer to implement callback. (i.e. why pass reference), when I can do without that.

Also, we can implement `qsort, bsearch` without function pointer to provide callback in them. So, why do with *pointer to function* way.

Comment: They both work the same way - they're pointers to functions. Similar to how (in the context of your `main`) `myarray` and `&myarray` both point to the same thing.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Almost there. `myarray` and `&myarray` don't point to the same thing.

Comment: So, why people prefer `int(*foo)(void)` instead of `int foo()`

Comment: @ashish2expert Because it's 1. more explicit, 2. closer to the truth.

Comment: @ashish2expert Correct observation!

Comment: "Note that, here I use normal function call." No, it is not a normal function call! It's a function pointer, just using a different syntax.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight If not, it means I can use that also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void populate_array(int *array, size_t arraySize,
        int getNextValue(void))  // Note that, here I use normal function call.
```

This is not a function call: you cannot have function calls inside declarations. `getNextValue` is a pointer to function that takes no arguments and returns an `int` declared using a different syntax.

Consider this analogy: you can define a new type for a pointer to `int` and use it in a declaration of a function

```
typedef int* intptr_t;
void myFunction(intptr_t ptr) {
    ...
}
```

or you can say that `ptr` is a pointer to `int` inside the declaration:

```
void myFunction(int* ptr) {
    ...
}
```

In the same way, you can define the type for your function pointer before using it in a declaration

```
typedef void generator_t(void);
void populate_array(int *array, size_t arraySize, generator_t getNextValue) {
}
```

or you could say that `getNextValue` is a function pointer using the alternative syntax from your post.

One reason to use a `typedef` for function pointers is consistency checking when you want to create arrays of function pointers: if your library function uses a function pointer defined inside that function's declaration, you would need to re-create the same declaration in your own code to create an array of pointers that you intend to pass to the library as pointers. This may lead to inconsistencies that would be visible only at the point of invocation of the library function, instead of the point of array declaration, making potential issues somewhat harder to trace.

Comment: So, why do it in a hard way, if we can do like that above

Comment: @ashish2expert Should I repeat myself? "Because it's 1. more explicit, 2. closer to the truth."

Comment: @ashish2expert Having a pointer type defined outside function declaration makes it easier to pass around pointers intended for consumption inside the target library.

Comment: It is not quite true that you cannot have a function call inside a declaration: `#include <stdio.h>`, `void foo(int a[][printf("Hello, world.\n")]) {}`, `int main(void) { foo(0); return 0; }` prints “Hello, world.”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Now **that**'s evil ;-)